# How to automatically add "Last Edited" in Java class documentation? (In Eclipse?)

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

There are some time stamps in JavaDoc like `last edited ----` . Is there a way to enter these details automatically whenever I edit and save a file?

Purpose is not to `SEE` the last edit date but `SHOW` it in javadocs. When I have finished editing and I am going to publish it. I don't want to write in every class's Javadocs myself when I edited the files last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no such feature in Eclipse with or without any plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly, however a better solution might be to use a version control on your code.  Not only will you be able to see the last date edited, you would be able to see each date you made a change, each version of the code, and hopefully a relevant comment as well.

Comment: Purpose is not to see the last edit date but show. When I have finished editing and I am going to publish it. I dont want to write in Javadocs myself when I edited the files last.

Comment: svn allow you to show the last commited date using svn:keywords date

Comment: @ohadshai javadocs will not pick that date? to add this to javadoc you will have to write it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/index.html#usage
```

Above plugin may help if you are using eclipse as IDE. Similar plugins probably exists for other IDEs as well if you search it through google

Comment: very useful but does not what I need.